# Can't get onActivityResult when starting an activity from a child activity in TabActivity Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

In MainActivity.java, I extends TabActivity to use Tabhost.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity
```

In each Tab, I use ActivityGroup to manage some child activity

```
public class MerchandiserTabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup
```

In a child activity A, I want to start another child activity B.

```
Intent intCreateClaim = new Intent(mContext, MultiPhotoSelectActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intCreateClaim, Parameter.ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

After I call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and `finish()` in Activity B, `onActivityResult()` in Activity A isn't called.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it called in the MainActivity ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't really the answer you're looking for, but you're using deprecated API. You should try a refactor and use the new Fragment API and the v4 support library if you need to support older versions of Android too. Using fragments you won't need to rely on setResult and onActivityResult.

[Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

[Fragment Tab Host](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because after B activity finishes, Android returns to your TabActivity, not your A activity.

Use fragments. This way you will not have to deal with multiple activities. You will have only one parent activity with fragments inside. To make your life easier and to add support for pre-ICS Android devices, try [GrilledUI](https://github.com/Auxx/grilledui) library.